# Spring-MVC bean Validation Type mismtach error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am trying to validate an object using Spring JSR303 validation, i have a form object which have some nested objects along with some form properties here is my Form signature

```
public class PaymentDetailsForm
{
  private AddressForm billingAddress;
  // other properties and getter and setters

}
```

In my `AddressForm` bean i have used Bean validation annotations to validate data, but i am not using any `@Valid` annotation inside my `PaymentDetailsForm` for `billingAddress`.
This is the signature of my Controller method

```
public String createUpdatePaymentInfos(final Model model,
@ModelAttribute("paymentInfo") @Valid final PaymentDetailsForm form, final BindingResult bindingResult)
{
}
```

If i am sending correct data from the form everything is working perfectly fine, but if i omit any field from `billingAddress` which is marked as required or not null i am getting following binding error exception

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'paymentInfo' on field 'billingAddress': 
rejected value [com.xxx.storefront.forms.AddressForm@e39f6f1,true]; 
codes [typeMismatch.paymentInfo.billingAddress,typeMismatch.billingAddress,typeMismatch.com.xxx.storefront.forms.AddressForm,typeMismatch];
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
codes [paymentInfo.billingAddress,billingAddress]; arguments []; default message [billingAddress]]; 
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' 
to required type 'com.xxx.storefront.forms.AddressForm' for property 'billingAddress';
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String[]] to required type [com.xxx.storefront.forms.AddressForm] for property 'billingAddress': 
no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

I was expecting that since i have not used `@valid` annotation for billingAddress property, it should not be validated but even in case it get validated i am not able to understand above mentioned exception/error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was due to some wrong mapping from UI,in my JSP page i was mapping address fields to `billingAddress` object but there was one hidden field like

```
<form:hidden path="billingAddress" id="billingAddress"/>
```

This was the cause of error since it was trying to send String array and Spring binding was unable to distinguish what i am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

The bindingResult that you are seeing doesn't look like it is because of validation errors, it is likely because of the binding errors - not being able to bind the UI fields to the inner billingAddress field. Even the binding errors would end up showing in the immediately following bindingresult argument like you are seeing.

Comment: i m agree with your input,i was just debugging this.What can be the cause of this since if i sent all data completely fields are getting mapped correctly only if some required data is missing this issue is coming